# arithmetic operation with columns in text file

Tags: scripts, text-processing

I have a data file which consists of two columns. I need to perform arithmetic operation with these columns as follows;

column_1=a(i) column_2=b(i), where `i` is the line number.

Calculations:

result_1=a(1)*100/b(1)

result_2=a(2)*100/b(2)

Then I need to write all results into another text file, consisting of columns. I tried below codes but all values look Inf.

```
nawk -F, '{print $1*100/$2}' data > results
```

Comment: No idea, what do you mean. Your `awk` command writes one column with the result for each line. Where is the problem?

Comment: Well , how does the actual data look like ?  Provide a couple of example lines to work with.

Comment: @serg, example data= 100 150; 200 2500. two columns and two rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code that you've said works, as discussed in the comments

```
xieerqi:
$ awk '{ print "a="$1" b="$2" result="($1*100)/$2   }' input.txt               
a=100 b=150 result=66.6667
a=200 b=2500 result=8

xieerqi:
$ cat inpu
input-10-       input.txt       inputData.txt   inputFile.txt   
$ cat input.txt                                                                
100 150
200 2500
```

You've also mentioned in the comments that last two lines in the output look like

```
a= b= result=-nan 
a= b= result=-nan
```

There is possibility your file contains two extra lines with spaces or non-printable characters. Run `cat -nA input.txt` to print the file with line numbers and show hidden characters

```
$ cat -nA input.txt                                                            
     1  100 150$
     2  200 2500
```

But overall this side issue is beyond the scope of what you've originally asked